# How to restrict by the file size and time periiod for which the file is allowed to be written

Tags: c, linux, file-io

I want to open a file and keep writing some logs in it. But restricting it

1. By the file size like 50kb or
2. By the time duration upto which the file will be allowed to be written.

Those are the only two conditions upto which the file will be allowed to be written and then it will create a backup of itself and restart the same process again for a fresh file. It will goes on and on. Backup file will be used later sometime to fill the database.

Any idea how to do it. And what functions I might use?

Comment: So it is YOUR program which is writing the file, so who is stopping you from keeping the track of the writing?

Answer (score 1):

File size limit you can achieve with this:

```
~/shell.sh | head -c 50K > test.log
```

File time limit you can achieve with this:

For 1 sec:
    timeout 1s ~/shell.sh > test.log

For 1 min

```
    timeout 1M ~/shell.sh > test.log
```

Answer (score 0):

To check the files status you can use [fstat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fstat).

It will return a structure which tells you last access time, and the total file size. If you want to know the time the file has been created, you need to keep track of it yourself though.

`fstat` works on a file descriptor so if you use `FILE` you must get the descriptor for it.

Answer (score 0):

**Timer:**

If you want to use timer in c, best way is using `alarm` function.

**Example:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

unsigned int timedout = 0;

void onAlarmTimeout(int signal) {
    timedout = 1;
}

int main() {
    signal(SIGALRM, onAlarmTimeout);

    printf("Setting Timer\n");

    alarm(10);

    while(timeout == 1);
    printf("Timeout..\n");

    return 0;
}
```

**File Size:**

To get file size, use:

- `stat`  - if you know the file name.
- `fstat` - if you have file descriptor.
- `lstat` - if you want to `stat` a file pointed by a symbolic-link.

and use the `st_size` member to get the total size of the file in bytes.

**Example:**

```
#include <sys/stat.h>
off_t getFileSize(const char *fileName) {
    struct stat st;
    if (stat(fileName, &st) == 0)
        return st.st_size;
    return -1;
}
```

or use:

do `fseek` to end of the file and call `ftell` to get the file size, but to use `fseek` and `ftell` method, you need to open the file as binary file by adding `b` to the file mode in `fopen` call.

**Example:**

```
// Error checking is ignored for clarity
FILE *fptr = fppen("file","rb");
// seek to end of the file
fseek(fptr, 0L, SEEK_END); 
size = ftell(fptr);
// seek back to beginning of file
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Here is an example code, which implements the log writing, here the file size is calculated based on the number of bytes written to file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <linux/limits.h>

unsigned int currentLogFileSize = 0;      // to store Log size
const unsigned int maxLogFileSize = 4096; // Max Log Size
const char* logFilePath = "./logFile";    // Log File Path
const unsigned int WRITETIME = 3;         // Write log time
unsigned int timedout = 0;                // timeout flag

FILE* logFilePtr = NULL;

FILE* openLogFile(const char* logFileName) {

    FILE* logFilePtr = NULL;

    // Open Log File
    if ((logFilePtr = fopen(logFilePath,"w")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot open file %s: %s\n",
            logFilePath, strerror(errno));
        return NULL;
    }

    timedout = 0;
    alarm(WRITETIME);       // Set alarm with WriteTime
    currentLogFileSize = 0; // Reset current log File size

    return logFilePtr;
}

// Backup the log File
int backupLog(void) {

    static count = 1; // for creating backup file name

    char newLogFilePath[PATH_MAX];
    snprintf(newLogFilePath,PATH_MAX,"%s_%d",logFilePath,count++);

    // Close previous log File
    if (fclose(logFilePtr) == -1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot close file %s: %s\n",
            logFilePath, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    // Rename the current file to new log File 
    if (rename(logFilePath,newLogFilePath) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot rename file %s to %s: %s\n",
            logFilePath, newLogFilePath, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    fprintf(stdout,"Backed Up log File %s to %s\n",logFilePath,newLogFilePath);

    // Open a the log File again for writing.
    if ((logFilePtr = openLogFile(logFilePath)) == NULL)
        return -1;

    return 0;
}

// On timer timeout call backup log function
void timeout_trigger(int sig) {
    timedout = 1;
}

// Write log File.
int fwriteLog(const char* strlog) {

    // if log File is not opened open a new log file
    if (logFilePtr == NULL)
        if ((logFilePtr = openLogFile(logFilePath)) == NULL)
            goto cleanUp;

    if (currentLogFileSize + strlen(strlog) >= maxLogFileSize) {
        fprintf(stdout,"Max Log File Size %d reached!...\n",currentLogFileSize);
        if (backupLog() == -1)
            goto cleanUp;
    }

    // on timeout
    if (timedout) {
        timedout = 0;
        fprintf(stdout,"Log Write timeout %d..\n",WRITETIME);
        if (backupLog() == -1)
            goto cleanUp;
    }

    if (fwrite(strlog,sizeof(char),strlen(strlog),logFilePtr) != strlen(strlog)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot write to file %s: %s\n",
                logFilePath, strerror(errno));
        goto cleanUp;
    }

    // Keep track of log file size
    currentLogFileSize += strlen(strlog);

    return 0;

// any error happens perform cleanup
cleanUp:
    fclose(logFilePtr);
    logFilePtr = NULL;
    currentLogFileSize = 0;
    return -1;

}

int main(void) {

    // on alarm timeout calls timeout_trigger function
    signal(SIGALRM, timeout_trigger);

    int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
        sleep(1);
        fwriteLog("logit\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```